# How wordpress checks to see if the current page is supposed to display multiple posts or a single post?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Need some clarification on wordpress basics.

I am trying to create a blog that shows a summary on the index page and one clicked shows the full blog.

I have the following loop in index, clicking on the title takes you to the post:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>

<h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
<p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
<hr> <?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
```

I don't know how this functions, how the links opens a new page with the post. Can any one explain how it checks to see if the current page is supposed to display a listing of multiple posts or a single post or page?

Once I have this I will focus on the summary on the index page opening the full post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated, the code you provided has come from the `index.php` file. This usually ends up being the homepage or the list of all the articles/pages posted from the admin.

Individual posts/pages that show the full content are generated using a different template, usually `page.php` or `single.php` with the exception of category specific templates.

To give you a run down of the code:

```
<?php 
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); // Runs the loop and gets post/page data
?> 
<h1>
    <?php the_title(); // Displays the title of the page?>
</h1>
<h2>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <?php the_title(); // displays the title again but this time with a link to the full story ?>
    </a>
</h2>

<h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); // this is the current date, not the post date ?></h4>
<p>
    <?php the_content(__('(more...)')); // gets the content up till it see's the more tag ?>
</p>
<hr> 
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>
    <?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); // error if nothing found ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Within the `page.php` or `single.php` it will have code to show just the single page, usually with commenting features and anything else which is usually excluded from a list view.

You can view the full list of template files and what they do here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files_List

Comment: Excellent gents, thank you. From both post I now get it, I will up vote one and accept the other. Excellent help!

Comment: Quick question, If I want to add a loop to another page (not index of single), sectionHome for example, is it possible? The loop isn't populated correctly, seems to return page details rather that posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So taking a closer look at your code:

---

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

The first have_posts() checks if your blog has posts to begin with. IF it has posts it executes the while. WHILE it has posts it tells to get the first post it encounters.

---

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
```

Grabs the title and permalink from the posts it took from the first line.

---

```
<h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
```

Shows the date the blog item was posted on (format being F, JS, Y).

---

```
<p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
```

Grabs the content from the posts it took from the first line.

---

```
<hr> <?php endwhile; else: ?>
```

Ends if the if statement on the first line isn't true anymore. I'll explain this further down below.

---

```
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
```

The else of the statement.

---

So i'm asuming your question is about the while statement since that is the part that lists each single post.

On the first line the part while (have_posts()) : the_post(); takes the first post it can find. Now the following lines (so the_title and the_permalink and the_content) are all grabbed from this first post and are placed on your website. Now you get to the line that says : endwhile. Now this is interesting since the while loops as long as there are posts. Since there are still posts that wordpress didnt go through yet it runs the while loop again, taking the first post it can find. So it places down the second post. Now assuming you only have 2 blog posts this is where the while loop ends and your endif gets executed.

If you have any more questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Excellent gents, thank you. From both post I now get it, I will up vote one and accept the other. Excellent help!

Comment: Quick question, If I want to add a loop to another page (not index of single), sectionHome for example, is it possible? The loop isn't populated correctly, seems to return page details rather that posts. Thanks.